# javascript preprocessors in java webapp

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, maven, gulp

How do you structure your project for full stack development, such that the js in /webapp could be processed by a gulp/grunt/webpack tools - in exploded war.

I know I can have maven/gradle add a step to perform some "npm thing", but that's a full build. I'll have that too, but I need the instant reload feature for development.

I want to be able to save a js file, have a watcher pick it up, process it and throw it back into my exploded war, in such a way that it a) doesn't pollute my /src/main/webapp/ b) I want it to coexist with my java webapp on the same root context (have my jsp's and eat it too).

One thing I considered is having my processes js outputed to some /src/main/webapp/do_not_checkin_folder and doing an equivalent of .gitignore on that directory. Followed up by, the full gradle/maven build that would rewrite paths in index.html removing any mention of do_not_checkin_folder and shortening the path to start from /src/main/webapp. Call it production mode.

Can someone suggest a different approach. What worked for you on your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Node server running Express that proxies most requests to my Java web server, except for the js requests, which it uses webpack hot middleware to serve.

Webpack is configured to use the contents src/main/js with webpack-hot-middleware to generate the single js page.

So in development, you navigate the to Node Express server. In production, the static js file is served by the Java web server.

Here's my server.js for Node:

```
const PROXY_TARGET = 'http://localhost:9501';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const config = require('./webpack.config-hot-middleware');
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require( 'http-proxy' );
const proxyServer = proxy.createProxyServer( );

proxyServer.on('error', function(err, req, res) {
    console.log('Proxy error: ' + err);
    res.writeHead(500, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('Proxy request to ' + PROXY_TARGET + ' failed. Please make sure your Java server is running!');
});

const app = new require('express')();
const port = 3000;

const compiler = webpack(config);
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    proxyServer.web(req, res, {
        target: PROXY_TARGET
    });
});

app.listen(port, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.info('==> Listening on port %s.);
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.